# mysql- select a product from one table by id, then its associated images from another table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table of products and one of images. Each product has multiple images. I want to retrieve a product based on its id and get all of its associated images. I have this query so far but it's not returning anything... would appreciate some help.

```
$result = mysqli_query(
    $link, sprintf("
        SELECT * FROM products product 
        JOIN images image 
        ON product.id = image.product_id 
        WHERE product.id='%s'", 
        mysqli_escape_string($link, $id)
    )
);
```

Comment: Is `product.id` an integer?

Comment: Yes, product.id is an integer

Comment: Then the `WHERE` clause should be: `product.id = %d`. (It will not fix your problem, but just a comment.) As for answering the question we need a little more to go on. What do your tables look like? Are you sure `$id` is an integer?

Comment: What happens when you insert an id yourself?

Comment: Facepalm! I was giving it an image id, not a product id. Thanks kabuto. Sorry guys!

Comment: i have question about fetching one image against one product like. One product has many (4) images but i only want to show only one image against that product.

Answer (score 1):

SELECT * FROM products JOIN images ON products.id = images.product_id WHERE products.id='%s'

Comment: it is a good approach you use. but i have question about fetching one image against one product like. One product has many (4) images but i only want to show only one image against that product.